# sending data from BTLE service to view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, btle

I am loosely following this tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/85900/arduino-tutorial-integrating-bluetooth-le-ios-swift

to write an app which reads streaming data from a BTLE peripheral. The app clearly demonstrates how to send data from my ViewController to the BTLE service to my microcontroller but I can't figure out how to get data in the other direction.

I have access to the data in the BTService object and I can print it out in the console but how would I update say a textBox from the BTService object?

I can find tons of iOS Swift tutorials but they all seem focused on things being triggered from the view controller. I can't find much on observing data in real time from the view controller.

Comment: You either need to issue a read request and then wait for a callback to `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` or if the characteristic supports it, you can enable notification and you will get a call to `didUpdateValueForCharacterisric` whenever the peripheral changes the characteristic value.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I have that working. I don't understand how to pass that data back to my ViewController. ViewController created an instance of the BTService (which implements the core Bluetooth protocol) but I don't understand how to pass that data to the view controller. I only see how to send data from the ViewController to the BTService. Do I have to request the data from the ViewController as well? I dug into the example a little further and it looks like he is using NSNotificationCenter (I think that's what it's called) to signal the ViewController when the connection status change

Comment: Ok.  I thought you had a problem with the BLE side of things.  It sounds like you should use a delegation pattern.  Implement a protocol and have the view controller set itself as the BTService's delegate